# How do I setup an azure local domain zone space

Tags: azure, dns, azure-virtual-machine, zone

Is there a way to create a local domain name (i.e. .cloud)
inside my azure account to point to internal IPs? (10.0.0.0/16)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Azure provides a default DNS based on hostnames for VMs in a VNET. If you just need simple name-ip resolution. Additionally you can provision your own DNS server, and assign it to the vnet or nic:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-name-resolution-for-vms-and-role-instances

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to create a local domain name (i.e. .cloud) inside my
>   azure account to point to internal IPs? (10.0.0.0/16)

Do you mean you want to use a customer domain name?

If yes, we can should buy a domain name, and deploy a VM  on Azure, and point the domian name to this VM, add DNS roles on it. Other VMs use this VM's private IP as DNS server, in this way, we can use customer domain name.

> Azure DNS does not currently support purchasing of domain names. If
>   you want to purchase domains, you need to use a third-party domain
>   name registrar.

For example, we can use DNS in this way:
[image]